# Determing Coordinate Transformation

Tags: python, matrix, coordinates, coordinate-transformation

Thank you in advance for taking the time to think about this....

I have an instrument that utilizes a solar tracker. The solar tracker can move in the azimuth and elevation to track the sun. To determine how well the solar tracker is doing an image of the sun is projected on to a CCD.

Because of the optical path, a change in elevation angle does not solely correspond to a change in y pixels and a change in the azimuth angle does not solely correspond to a change in the x pixels.

I would like to determine the relationship between changes in the elevation and azimuth angle and changes in the x & y pixels. I think I need a 2D transformation matrix with rotation and scaling.

I can run a sort of calibration where I move the tracker a delta elevation angle (Az) and get a delta x (x1) and y (y1) pixel value and move it a delta azimuth (Elv) and get another delta x (x2) and y (y2) pixel value

Using this calibration, how can I determine the relationship such that given a delta x and delta y I can determine how much to change the elevation and azimuth angles on the tracker.

If possible I would like to program this in Python.

Also, a quick follow up question. What if the response isn't necessarily linear. Such that moving the tracker elevation 0.25 degrees, produces a different ratio of delta x and y pixels than moving it say 1.5 degrees. How would one deal with this?

Thanks again for your time and consideration!

Comment: What exactly *is* your question? Do you know how to do this mathematically? Have you actually written any code?

Comment: Honestly, I think this is a math problem more than anything.  Once you know the math, you should be able to rewrite in python pretty easily.  Maybe try posting [over here](http://math.stackexchange.com/) and then once you have the math down, try to write it in python.  If you hit a roadblock at that point, I would bring it back here.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Good point. I guess I'm trying to figure out the math first. I have a feeling that it would be solving the equation y = Ax for A, where y is a vector of azimuth and elevation angles and x is a vector of the corresponding x and y pixels.

Comment: Unfortunately open-ended questions like this are off-topic on Stack Overflow.  Since you mentioned you're looking for a Pythonic solution to your problem, there is a mailing list called [AstroPy](http://mail.scipy.org/mailman/listinfo/astropy) that is good for discussing the tackling of astronomy-related problems with Python, and someone there is likely to have ideas (from the sound of it this can probably be achieved with astropy's coordinates library).

Comment: @StickyKeyboard I don't quite understand your question. When you say optical path, do you mean optical path through the instrument? Or as in path traced on the sky? Or are you trying to map pixels in images you take with the actual eq. coords on the sky? For just 1 image  ("solving") or for all images you make? Are you trying to measure quality of tracking? Small patches of sky are well approximated linearly. That's tangent plane projection (TAN). Look at World Coord. Sys. and FITS file format if you want to map everything. You've a lot reading to do depending on what's your goal.